# How do I know who has downloaded my application from market?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to upload an app in android market. I need to know the legal installations on devices. So is there any information available to developers to know who has downloaded their apps from market. Because, one thing i am sure is that a person can not download an application unless he is not signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use licensing

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Comment: Thanks longhairedsi, for the prompt reply. It looks quite helpful.

Comment: One more thing please. My application allows user to interact with backend server. So is this possible using this licensing service to validate that the user requesting for some service from server is a legitimate user?

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically a programming subject, but if your application is for sale you can log into the Android Market publishing site and then click on the link to your Google Checkout account: every individual who has paid for your application will have an order entry with full details about who they are in the Google Checkout orders page.